# Do 3rd party libraries gets imported into a compiled python script?

Tags: python

im curios how the whole compiling thing of python is working, lets say I have a Linux machine and Im writing a small script in python with the library [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) and now I would like to know what happens then I compile the code to an .exe file with [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) does the Windows machine still needs to have the OpenCV library installed? Or does it gets added to the compiled script?

Comment: PyInstaller 'packs' all dependencies/libraries into the exe, there is no need to have anything installed.

Comment: oh alright, this is it, thank you!